# Generate JSON without top tag in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm writing an API that sends stuff through a socket. What I want to do, is have a basic response like so:

```
{
  method: ID,
  id: 10
}
```

The first tag being the type of stuff being sent, and everything after that is content. I can't seem to figure out how to do that with Groovy's `JsonBuilder`.

I'm reading the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) for that, and I attempted to do:

```
String message = builder.value {
    method: Method.ID
    id: id
}
```

But it only generates: `{value={}}`. Also, it contains the `value` tag (which I don't want).

I tried doing `builder {...}`, but that caused this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: website.DerbyProManagerService.builder() is applicable for argument types: (website.DerbyProManagerService$DerbyProInstance$_newId_closure1) values: [website.DerbyProManagerService$DerbyProInstance$_newId_closure1@6db853f4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
String message = builder.call {
    method Method.ID
    id myId
}
```